# SQL Server 2005 Bulk insert on split string where not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a problem with an insert statement where I cannot get the "where not exists" clause to work. I would prefer a solution where I do not have to dump my list into a declared a table. Here are two of the solutions I have tried, could someone please tell where my syntax is wrong? My split string list has three values, the first two values would be new, but the third value already exists in the database and so should not be inserted.

With this sample I get no data returned at all:

```
 insert into dbo.Cook(Id, CookId, DateEntered, Active) 
    select 
        @Id, value as CookId, getDate(), 1 
    from 
        dbo.Split('123456,234567,345678', ',')
    left join 
       dbo.Cook ck on ck.Id = @Id
    where 
       not exists (select CookId from dbo.Cook where Id = @Id)
```

Then I tried a version with a table which winds up returning all the values in my @ids table including the cook number that would be a duplicate:

```
 declare @ids table (id int)

 insert into @ids 
     select value as id 
     from dbo.Split('123456,234567,345678', ',')

 insert into dbo.Cook(Id, CookId, DateEntered, Active) 
    select 
       @Id, id as CookId, getDate(), 1 
    from 
       @ids
    left outer join 
       dbo.Cook ck on ck.CookId = id
    where 
       not exists (select CookId from dbo.Cook where ck.CookId != id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution to my problem, thanks goes out to a fellow programmer. My problem was I should have being doing the join on the select statement and adding a comparison column to get the information I was looking for. The solution was this:

```
insert into dbo.Cook(Id, CookId, DateEntered, Active) 
select 
    @Id, value as CookId, getDate(), 1
from 
    dbo.Split('123456,234567,345678', ',') c
left join 
   (select cook from dbo.Cook where Id = @Id) cook on cook.Id = c.value
where 
   cook.Id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from your neglecting to put your `from` clause on a new line *cringe*, I believe it is your syntax.

I don't understand what you are trying to do here. `dbo.Split` is not a built in function in SQL Server as far as I know.

Comment: dbo.Split is just a call to another sql procedure that takes the string and returns the list to a table